# Create custom endpoint with custom route tutorial

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Is there any way to create my custom endpoint on MediaWiki, for example:

```
http://my.wikiexample.com/custom/deleteAccount
```

I did some search but I found info only for APIsandbox and REST API, which does not give any info to create custom endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to create a arbitrary path like that (although there's some [discussion](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T104755) about introducing a generic router one day), but you can easily add custom modules to the MediaWiki API.

For example, you could implement http://my.wikiexample.com/w/api.php?action=deleteuser in a similar way to how [CentralAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CentralAuth) does the  `deleteglobalaccount` action. See [API:Extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Extensions) for more.

(There are also other [DeleteAccount extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:DeleteAccount_extensions) that use the [UserMerge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserMerge) extension's deletion mechanism, if that's what you're trying to do).

Comment: Just a question because i am new on mediawiki. Do i have to develop a new extension and then add custom api on this module. Or i can add custom  api

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to create an extension to create a new API module.